# filter dataframe after groupby and nunique in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

i tried `df.groupby("item")["variable"].nunique()` and it returns a unique count of every item object.

i want to filter to only return the count of "variable" > 3 conditional on Groupby item... is there a method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want the `groupby` to be mapped to every row of the input, think about `transform`:

```
df = df[df.groupby("item")["variable"].transform('nunique') > 3]
```

Comment: Lastly, for the length of the dataFrame, use `len(df)`.

Comment: actually wanted something like this: 

`df["item"][df.groupby("item")["variation"].transform('nunique') > 3].nunique()`

or 

`sum(df.groupby("item")["variation"].nunique() > 3)`

which calculated the number of "items" 

because `len(df)` was basically the length of the original df.